# Decrypt TLS Traffic from PCAP

Tags: ssl, encryption, cryptography, wireshark, pcap

I have a PCAP file that was given to me for a Forensics Challenge.  The PCAP has encrypted traffic using TLS Version 1.  I have looked into a BEAST attack but there are no tools to do this.  Is there any way using just the packets I have in the PCAP file to decrypt this traffic in Wireshark without the private key? Can I get the private key from the certificate exchange in anyways or the master secret log or something? I could not find any tutorials online that do not involve having access to the private key.  Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

My later research revealed that version 1 of TLS did have vulnerabilities and that it was possible to do but I would have needed access to the actual host as well not just the PCAP of its traffic.

Comment: This is not going to work. TLS is *designed* to prevent these sorts of attacks.

Comment: Just reading your update. "*I would have needed access to the actual host*"... Sure, if you have access to the host, why bother with a network capture at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the master secret, you might be able to do something.

Have a look at the "Using the (Pre)-Master-Secret" section on the [SSL page of the Wireshark wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL). You'll need a reasonably recent version of Wireshark, which adds the ability to set the master secret (instead of expecting the server's private key). This should also help for Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman cipher suites.

More details in [this question](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/4229/follow-ssl-stream-using-master-key-and-session-id) on the Wireshark Q&A site.